# Trying to sand class object between intents by parcelable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, constructor, parcelable

I have a bit trouble implementing Parcelable. Here's how I did it:

```
public class Player implements Parcelable{
    String name;
    int score;
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeInt(score);
    }

    public Player(Parcel source){
        score = source.readInt();
        name = source.readString();
    }
}

public class MyCreator implements Parcelable.Creator<Player> {

    @Override
    public Player createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Player(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Player[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Player[size];
    }

}
```

This was the whole code implementing Parcelable. Now I'm trying to create a new class object:

```
Player newPlayer = new Player(null);
newPlayer.name = text;
newPlayer.score = 0;
playersParceledData.add(newPlayer);
zacniIgro.putParcelableArrayListExtra("parceledData", playersParceledData);
```

This is the line that is bothering me:

```
Player newPlayer = new Player(null);
```

Is the fact that I just insrted "null" okay? Or do I have to  insert something else between those ()? I was following [this example](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html) and this isn't explained in it. It says that a new object should be created like this:

```
Player newPlayer = new Player();
```

But I am not allowed to do this since I made a constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an additional constructor for use cases you're not using `Parcel` to construct your object, for example

```
public class Player implements Parcelable{
    /* ... */

    public Player(Parcel source){
        /* ... */
    }

    public Player(int score, String name){
        this.score = score;
        this.name = name; 
    }
}
```

Then you can construct objects both from `Parcel` and using an `int` and an `String`:

```
final Player aPlayer = new Player(10000, "SomeRandomPlayerName");
```

---

Also, you read the `int` and the `String` in inverse order as you write them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you just additionally explains your last sentence? What do you mean by reading them in reverse order?

Comment: It means when you write the parcel you're doing it in `String, int` order. When you read it, you're reading in `int, String` order.

Comment: This is related to your question but your code in general, you write to parcel using `dest.writeString(name)` followed by `dest.writeInt(score)`, while you read from parcel using `source.readInt()` followed by `source.readString()`. So your read it in a different order than you write it.